# Where to store sensitive data in a C# assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, reflector

Given that a C# assembly can be easily reverse engineered using reflector, where should I store my sensitive data when compiling an assembly in C#?

I have a X509certificate embedded in my C# assembly in which I need to store the password when accessing the certificate! Now where should I store the certificate password?

Comment: You can't.  Anything that your code can access, the user can also access.

Comment: Encryption would be your only option: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316898    But ultimately, nothing is secure.

Comment: Keep you sensitive data in protected (encrypted) mode.

Comment: any other solutions? an unmanaged library maybe?

Comment: You can encrypt part of your app.config file: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx

Comment: The consensus is that it can't be done.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073110/could-i-hide-the-encryption-key-of-a-c-sharp-exe-securely-in-a-way-that-cant-b/7073162#7073162) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288/protecting-api-secret-keys-in-a-thick-client-application).

Comment: @Anon: Encryption doesn't help in the slightest.

Comment: @Sepehr: No.  The user has complete control over anything running on his machine.

Comment: The best I've used is Secure Team (http://www.secureteam.net/NET-Obfuscator-Features.aspx) but its not cheap.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind shelling out some cash, you could take a look at [Eazfuscator](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net/features)

The vendor claims to offer **Code virtualization**, string encryption among other features.

If his claims are valid, this might be what you need.

They have a trial, so i guess it can't hurt to try it out.